# How to use Swagger in non-trivial Wildfly Swarm project?

Tags: swagger, wildfly-swarm

In a very simple Wildfly Swarm project Swagger works fine and produces the expected `swagger.json` output. But as soon as a second java package is added to the project, it doesn't work anymore.

Example (see https://github.com/pe-st/swagger42 example project):

- the first commit consists of the project as generated by http://wildfly-swarm.io/ (containing one class `HelloWorldEndpoint` in the package `ch.schlau.pesche.swagger42.rest`)
- the second commits adds minimal Swagger annotations and generates the following `swagger.json` :

  ```
  {
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {},
    "basePath": "/",
    "paths": {
      "/hello": {
        "get": {
          "summary": "Get the response",
          "description": "",
          "operationId": "doGet",
          "produces": [
            "text/plain"
          ],
          "parameters": [],
          "responses": {
            "default": {
              "description": "successful operation"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- the third commit adds an empty class in a second java package `ch.schlau.pesche.swagger42.core`. Now the generated `swagger.json` looks like this:

  ```
  {"swagger":"2.0","info":{},"basePath":"/"}
  ```

What has to be done to make Swagger work in projects like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://wildfly-swarm.gitbooks.io/wildfly-swarm-users-guide/advanced/swagger.html

Create a file META-INF/swarm.swagger.conf

and add following entry:

```
packages:ch.schlau.pesche.swagger42.rest
```

---

There is a info in the startup:

```
[org.wildfly.swarm.swagger] (main) WFSSWGR0004: Configure Swagger for deployment 
demo.war with package ch.schlau.pesche.swagger42.core
```

or similar, which packages is scanned.

Comment: Yes that works (I also tried to set the packages in the project-defaults.yml, but there it didn't work). Thanks!